# Why Python 3.6 Dictionary when imported and updated all nested key denotes same memory location

Tags: python, dictionary

The project I'm working on has a global file global_parameter which holds all global variable to be imported and used around the project,

The file contains a global dictionary  env_data which hold temp data for calculation purpose
Here is a sample section that I'm working

```
{"application_name1": {"request_details": {...}, "application_details": {...}},
 "application_name2": {"request_details": {...}, "application_details": {...}}}
```

Memory Location of each dictionary in request_deatils for all application points to the same memory location,

Do we any reason for this python behavior

Comment: what is happening when you change value in one `request_details` ? Is this changing value in other `request_details` ? Maybe you assign the same dictionary to may variables. Maybe you should use `copy.deepcopy()` to duplicante them.

Comment: "Memory Location of each dictionary in request_deatils for all application points to the same memory location" Of course it does. Why would you expect it to work differently? `import` doesn't re-run all the code and copy everything. Python never works that way

Comment: Probably, a more fundamental problem is you are relying on *mutable* global state.

Comment: > Memory Location of each dictionary in request_deatils for all application points to the same memory location,
do you mean `id(data['application_name1']['request_details']) == id(data['application_name1'])`?

Comment: Okay let me rephrase and point to more details I have sample dictionary in sample_json package which act as blueprint of the json that I want to have so that I don't fill field in runtime , this json get imported and updated and then stored at env_data for each application
After importing for all application I re-instantiate the json as 
variable = dict(imported_dict)
i have checked all id(variable) they show different address but when I updated sub dictionary of any application that operation gets applied to all applications json

Comment: @furas Tried .copy() still the same

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga after I import JSON i instantiate it by myself by calling dict() on it 
should I consider storing data into DB than runtime but trade-off is the speed of execution

Comment: @tomy0608 No I mean
id(data['application_name1']['request_details']['pass_curl']) == id(data['application_name2']['request_details']['pass_curl'])

Comment: Also, Thing that i want to point out which might be useful is that this project is a multithreaded project all the thread uses a mutable global variable to get required data

Comment: `.copy()` makes only shallow copy (it duplicates only first level but it other levels keeps reference to the same objects). If you have nested elements then you have to use `copy.deepcopy()` to copy also nested elements.

Comment: and reason is that `a = dictionary` and `a = list` doesn't duplicate dictionary/list because it needs more time and new memory, and usually people want to work with the same dictionary/list (but in other function). If you wan to duplicate dictionary/list then you have to use `copy` or `deepcopy` (for nested elements).